# Getting null value using intent

Tags: android

I am getting null value using intent because of that I am not able to code further. Here I'm send data from one intent to next but not work here. I'm getting null value but I'm sending specific value i.e temp_id

firstActivity.java

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id)
        {

            super.onItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

         final Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);

         String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( Constants.GREETING_NAME ));
        final int template_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex( Constants.KEY_ID_GREET ));
        String temp_id=String.valueOf(template_id);


         goForEdit(temp_id);

         //confirm
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Name :"+name+"  id : " + temp_id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();    
         }

        public void goForEdit(String temp_id){
            Intent launchSMSTempEdit = new Intent(
                    ManageEmailTemplate.this,
                                EmailTempEdit.class);

            if(!(temp_id==null))
            {
            launchSMSTempEdit.putExtra("temp_id",temp_id);
            startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);
            }
        }
```

next activity

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_template);




        sms_key_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");

        if(sms_key_id == null) {
            sms_key_id = "empty string";
        }

        if (sms_key_id.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            //do whatever

        } else {
        //do whatever
            sms_key_id="1";
       System.out.println("KEY ID==="+sms_key_id);

        }



        Toast.makeText(this, "CODE:::"+ mTemplateType + "  id =="+ sms_key_id  ,          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Log cat:

```
09-04 12:23:27.261: I/ActivityManager(1224): Displayed com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility/.ManageEmailTemplate: +390ms
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606): Process: com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility, PID: 3606
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility/com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility.EmailTempEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility.EmailTempEdit.onCreate(EmailTempEdit.java:145)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
09-04 12:23:29.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3606):     ... 10 more
09-04 12:23:29.819: W/ActivityManager(1224):   Force finishing activity 1 com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility/.EmailTempEdit
```

Answer (score 3):

You are putting id with key `temp_id` in first activity and trying to read it with `called` that's why you are not receiving it in next activity. I next activity change `sms_key_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");` to   `sms_key_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("temp_id");`

Comment: thanq sir!!   but again i'm getting Run time error    i add logcat errors

Comment: Don't post logcat as answer.. edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (sms_key_id.equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
```

with

```
if (sms_key_id!=null && sms_key_id.equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First - You are sending the intent with one key *temp_id* and fetching the value out of it using the other key *called*

Second - From your logs, look for the  *Caused by*  which will tell you the reason for the RuntimeException and the line number of the problematic code for that. In your case it is  *EmailTempEdit.java:145*

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem where it was. I was correct that yes in line 145  there was a problem. Actually I didn't take intent (`mTemplateType=getIntent().getStringExtra("template_type")`) for this code.

```
if(mTemplateType.equals("email")){
            message = subject + subjectMessageDelimiter + message;  //|~| is the delimiter
            messageTypeCode = Constants.EMAIL_CODE;
        } else if(mTemplateType.equals("sms")){
            messageTypeCode = Constants.SMS_CODE;
        }
```